# Firebase reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential problems

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Method `reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential` requires `credential`.

I tried this and it gives me an error:

```
const user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
const credential = firebase.auth.OAuthCredential;
await user.reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential);
await user.updateEmail(email);
return email;
```

Error message

> reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential failed: First argument "credential" must be a valid credential.

I only have oath authentication (no email + password). So I can't figure out what `credential` firebase need. Any help?

**Edit:**
For some reason my `firebase.auth.OAuthCredential` or (`firebase.auth.AuthCredential`) return undefined. User is signedIn/authed.

Comment: Can you try it with the [accessToken](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.OAuthCredential#accessToken) property of the credential?

Comment: For some reason my `firebase.auth.OAuthCredential` or (firebase.auth.AuthCredential) return `undefined`. User is authed

Comment: That sounds like very useful information to include in your question. Unfortunatly I won't be able to help you any further :(

Answer (score 5):

Ran into this issue in a Vue.js project where we have a `firebase.js` file that handles module imports and exports of `const`.

Hoping this will help someone save time when using a similar setup.

File: `firebase.js`

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/database'


// Initialize Firebase
const app = firebase.initializeApp(options)
export const fb = firebase
export const auth = app.auth()
export const db = app.database()
export const functions = app.functions()
```

Example of `changePassword()` in other script file or inside `*.vue`

```
import { fb, auth } from './firebase.js'
...
changePassword() {
  if (yourFormValidation == true) {
    let user = auth.currentUser

    const credentials = fb.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
      user.email,
      this.current_password
    )
    user.reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credentials)
      .then(() => {
        user.updatePassword(this.new_password)
          .then(() => {
            console.log('your password was successfully changed.')
          })
          .catch(error => console.log(error))
      })
      .catch(error => console.log(error.message))
  }
}
```

**Where I was running into `Cannot read property 'credential' of undefined"`...**

Importing only `{ auth } from './firebase.js` and then calling `auth.EmailAuthProvider()`.

**How to access other classes found on [firebase.auth()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth)...**

1. `export const fb = firebase` in `firebase.js`
2. `import { fb, auth } from './firebase.js'` where you are writing your function
3. Call `fb.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential()` or other class needed

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation for reauthenticating the user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#re_authenticate_a_user) shows this example:

> ```
> var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
> var credential;
>
> // Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials
>
> user.reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).then(function() {
>   // User re-authenticated.
> }).catch(function(error) {
>   // An error happened.
> });
> ```

Your code fails to implement the comment correctly. You will need to show a prompt to the user to provide their credentials again, put those into the correct credential object type, and pass that in.

For example:

> ```
> var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(
>     email,
>     password
> );
> ```

Comment: For the credential, where did those two arguments (`email` and `password`) come from?

Comment: @FiringBlanks take a look [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider#.credential)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subscription to watch for the changes. Use AngularFire to watch for when they are logged in and get the UID (assuming you are using the Authentication login in Firebase so that all data is saved using the UID as the tree path.

You can also add a set timeout to unsubscribe them after a given time

```
   import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
    import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
    import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
    import { switchMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { Observable,  pipe } from 'rxjs';
    import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
    import firebase as firebase from 'firebase/app';

private myOAuthSubscription: Subscription;
private myDatasubscription: Subscription;    
public userloggedin:boolean = false;
public uid:string = '';
private functionhasrun:boolean = false;

    public this.items:any = [];

    constructor(
      public _DB: AngularFireDatabase,
      public _afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    ) {

    //check that the user is logged in 
    try {
      this.myOAuthSubscription = this._afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {

        if (user && user.uid) {

          console.log('loggedin = true');
          this.userloggedin = true;
          this.uid = String(user.uid);

          if(this.functionhasrun==false){

           this.functionhasrun = true;
           this.funDoDB():

          }

        } else {

        console.log('loggedin = false');
        this.userloggedin = true;
        this.uid = '';

        }
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error("fbData_subscription", e);
    }



    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
      this.myOAuthSubscription.unsubscribe();
      this.myDatasubscription.unsubscribe();
    }


    private funDoDB(){
          if(this.userloggedin == true){
          try {

        //subscription using AngulaFire
        this.myDatasubscription = this._DB.list('myDataPath/' + this.uid).snapshotChanges().pipe(map(actions => {
            return actions.map(action => ({ key: action.key, val: action.payload.val() }));
          }))
          .subscribe(items => {

            this.items = [];
            this.items = items.map(item => item);

            console.log("db results",this.items);

            var icount=0;

            for (let i in this.items) {

             console.log("key",this.items[i].key);
             console.log("val",this.items[i].val); 
             console.log("----------------------------------);

             //checking if something exists
             if (this.items[i].key == 'SomeNodePath') {
               var log = this.items[i].val;
             }

            }


          } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
          }


          });
        }
        }

    npm install --save angularfire2 firebase
    npm install -D rxjs@6.2.2 rxjs-compat@6.2.2
```

Comment: It's not the answer for my question