# Firebase Auth - Trouble Reauthenticating User Using GoogleAuthProvider

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

As per the docs, I need to reauthenticate the user who is trying to delete their account but hasn't signed in for a while. Here is the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users) (very bottom):

**Documentation**

> If you perform one of these actions, and the user signed in too long
>   ago, the action fails with an error. When this happens,
>   re-authenticate the user **by getting new sign-in credentials from the
>   user** and passing the credentials to reauthenticateWithCredential

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
var credential;

// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials

user.reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).then(function() {
  // User re-authenticated.
})
```

**Credential?**

My issue is in the *getting new sign-in credentials from the user* part. What value is the credential variable supposed to have? According to [Puff's comment here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51728165/1834148), it's supposed to go:

```
var credential = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(email, password);
```

My question: Where do the email and password come from? Since I'm using **GoogleSignInAuth**, the email could be retrieved with `firebase.auth().currentUser.email`, so it would look like this:

```
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
let credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(firebase.auth().currentUser.email);

user.reauthenticateAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential).then(() => {
  // User re-authenticated.
});
```

But I'm getting an error:

> {"error":{"code":400,[{"message":"Unable to parse Google
>   id_token:qmnofficial@gmail.com", "domain":"global","reason":"invalid"}]}}

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

your problem here is you are trying to retrieve google credentials by using an email address, that is not possible.

```
let credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(firebase.auth().currentUser.email);
```

according to the docs,

> credential(idToken, accessToken) returns firebase.auth.OAuthCredential
>
> Creates a credential for Google. At least one of ID token and access
>   token is required.

```
var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(id_token);
```

or

```
var credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(null,access_token);
```

for your use case do it like this,

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.reauthenticateWithPopup(
    new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()).then(function(userCredential) {
        // You can now delete the user:
        return firebase.auth().currentUser.delete();  
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Credential mismatch or some other error.  
    }
);
```

hope it helps.